# Querystring blocked in a POST request to azure cloud WCF service

Tags: wcf, rest, azure, cloud

I have a problem with the WCF REST service published in Azure cloud: the service recieves the call but the entire querystring is missing, all the parameters contained in POST url are empty.

Here is the contract defined for the service

```
    <ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IRestServiceImpl

    <OperationContract>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
                BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate:="sendNotification?reason={reason}&eventDate={eventDate}&originalReference={originalReference}&merchantReference={merchantReference}&" & _
                "currency={currency}&pspReference={pspReference}&merchantAccountCode={merchantAccountCode}&eventCode={eventCode}&" & _
                "value={value}&operations={operations}&success={success}&paymentMethod={paymentMethod}&live={live}")>
    Function sendNotification(eventDate As String, reason As String, originalReference As String, merchantReference As String,
                         currency As String, pspReference As String, merchantAccountCode As String, eventCode As String,
                         value As String, operations As String, success As String, paymentMethod As String, live As String) As String

End Interface
```

ANd the implementing function in the service

```
    Public Function sendNotification(eventDate As String, reason As String, originalReference As String, merchantReference As String, currency As String, pspReference As String, merchantAccountCode As String, eventCode As String, value As String, operations As String, success As String, paymentMethod As String, live As String) As String Implements Common.IRestServiceImpl.sendNotification

    Return "Got iT!"

End Function
```

Here follows the relewant config part, for the webrole

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name = "PaymentServiceWebRole.AdyenNotificationService" 
           behaviorConfiguration = "myServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint name="webHttpBinding"
              address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="TripRebelCommon.ServiceContracts.IRestServiceImpl"
              behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
              >
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

And the URL used to post data:

http://*******.cloudapp.net/MyService.svc/sendNotification?pspReference=8814002409046667&eventDate=2014-05-16T11:48:28.01Z&merchantAccountCode=TriprebelCOM&reason=36069:1111:6/2016&originalReference=&value=10&eventCode=AUTHORISATION&merchantReference=33&operations=CANCEL,CAPTURE,REFUND&success=true&paymentMethod=mc&currency=EUR&live=false

So, the problem is that when external service does the test, i receive only the 
"/MyService.svc/sendNotification"

With no QUeryString included at all. I i do the same call from my local PC to a cloud service using Fiddler - it all works fine, i receive the date and process it.

The worst part is - it have worked a week ago when i did the first test and now this is driving me nuts, as i canno see any obvious problem here, but i must be missing some small thing that brakes this.

Would appreciate any help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this myself.

To anyone who will have the same kind of problem:

Basically i have been trying to implement Adyen payment provider solution. The problem was in the way they send the data - tech support says it is in the URL like the original post states,  but in reality the parameter string 
pspReference=8814002409046667&eventDate=2014-05-16T11:48:28.01Z&merchantAccountCode=TriprebelCOM&reason=36069:1111:6/2016&originalReference=&value=10&eventCode=AUTHORISATION&merchantReference=33&operations=CANCEL,CAPTURE,REFUND&success=true&paymentMethod=mc&currency=EUR&live=false

is being send inside the request BODY and in order to handle it properly, the only input parameter for the receiving function must be a STREAM, whichy will containt the above mentioned string.